# Proving Muirhead’s inequality by AM-GM

Tags: permutations, contest-math, convex-optimization, symmetric-polynomials, muirhead-inequality

I don't understand the second proof of Muirhead’s inequality in [page 10-11](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2201.01270.pdf)

First prove \eqref{constantMuirhead} using AM-GM:

> Let $(c_i)_{i=1}^n$ be a sequence of real numbers such that $c_i \neq 0$ for some $i$ and
> $$
> \sum_{i=1}^n c_i = 0.
> $$
> For every pair of integers $(i,j)$ with $i,j \in \{1,\ldots, n\}$, there are $(n-1)!$ permutations
> $\sigma \in S_n$ with $\sigma(i) = j$ and so there are $(n-1)!$ permutations $\sigma$
> such that $x_{\sigma(i)}^{c_i} = x_j^{c_i}$.
> Therefore,
> \begin{align*}
> \prod_{\sigma \in S_n}  x_{\sigma(1)}^{c_1} x_{\sigma(2)}^{c_2} \cdots x_{\sigma(n)}^{c_n} 
> & = \prod_{\sigma \in S_n} \prod_{i=1}^n  x_{\sigma(i)}^{c_i} 
> = \prod_{i=1}^n \prod_{\sigma \in S_n}  x_{\sigma(i)}^{c_i}  \\
> & = \prod_{i=1}^n \prod_{j =1}^n  x_j^{(n-1)! c_i} 
> = \prod_{j =1}^n \prod_{i =1}^n x_j^{(n-1)! c_i} \\
> & =  \prod_{j =1}^n   x_j^{(n-1)! \sum_{i=1}^n c_i} = 1.
> \end{align*}
> Applying the arithmetic and geometric mean inequality to the nonconstant positive vector $\mathbf x$ gives
> $$
> 1 = \left( \prod_{\sigma \in S_n} x_{\sigma(1)}^{c_1} x_{\sigma(2)}^{c_2} \cdots x_{\sigma(n)}^{c_n} \right)^{1/n!} 
> < \frac{1}{n!}\sum_{\sigma \in S_n}  x_{\sigma(1)}^{c_1} x_{\sigma(2)}^{c_2} \cdots x_{\sigma(n)}^{c_n}
> $$
> and so
> $$
> n! < \sum_{\sigma \in S_n}  x_{\sigma(1)}^{c_1} x_{\sigma(2)}^{c_2} \cdots x_{\sigma(n)}^{c_n}.
> $$
> Equivalently,
> $$\tag7\label{constantMuirhead}
> 0 < \sum_{\sigma \in S_n}  \left( x_{\sigma(1)}^{c_1} x_{\sigma(2)}^{c_2} \cdots x_{\sigma(n)}^{c_n} - 1\right).
> $$

Then it proves Muirhead’s inequality using \eqref{constantMuirhead}:

> Let $\mathbf a = \left( \begin{smallmatrix} a_1 \\ \vdots \\ a_n \end{smallmatrix}\right)$ and $\mathbf b = \left( \begin{smallmatrix} b_1 \\ \vdots \\ b_n \end{smallmatrix}\right)$.
> For $i \in\{1,\ldots, n\}$, let
> $$
> c_i = a_i-b_i.
> $$
> The strict majorization relation $\mathbf b \prec \mathbf a$ implies that $c_i \neq 0$ for some $i$ and
> $$
> \sum_{i=1}^n c_i = \sum_{i=1}^n (a_i-b_i) = \sum_{i=1}^n a_i - \sum_{i=1}^n b_i  = 0.
> $$
> We have
> \begin{align}
> \sum_{\sigma \in S_n} \prod_{i=1}^n x_{\sigma(i)}^{a_i} 
> & = \sum_{\sigma \in S_n} \prod_{i=1}^n x_{\sigma(i)}^{b_i+c_i} 
>  = \sum_{\sigma \in S_n} \prod_{i=1}^n x_{\sigma(i)}^{b_i} \prod_{i=1}^n x_{\sigma(i)}^{c_i}.
> \end{align}
> Inequality \eqref{constantMuirhead} implies
> \begin{align}
> [\mathbf x^{\mathbf a}]_{S_n} - [\mathbf x^{\mathbf b}]_{S_n}
> & = \sum_{\sigma \in S_n} \prod_{i=1}^n x_{\sigma(i)}^{a_i} 
>  - \sum_{\sigma \in S_n} \prod_{i=1}^n x_{\sigma(i)}^{b_i} \\
> & = \sum_{\sigma \in S_n} \prod_{i=1}^n x_{\sigma(i)}^{b_i} \prod_{i=1}^n x_{\sigma(i)}^{c_i} 
>  - \sum_{\sigma \in S_n} \prod_{i=1}^n x_{\sigma(i)}^{b_i} \\
>  & = \sum_{\sigma \in S_n} \prod_{i=1}^n x_{\sigma(i)}^{b_i} 
>  \left( \prod_{i=1}^n x_{\sigma(i)}^{c_i} -1\right)  \\
>  & > 0.  
> \end{align}
> This completes the proof.

I can't prove the last step using \eqref{constantMuirhead}
$$\sum_{\sigma \in S_n} \prod_{i=1}^n x_{\sigma(i)}^{b_i} 
 \left( \prod_{i=1}^n x_{\sigma(i)}^{c_i} -1\right)   > 0 $$
An equivalent form of \eqref{constantMuirhead} is$$\sum_{\sigma \in S_n} 
 \left( \prod_{i=1}^n x_{\sigma(i)}^{c_i} -1\right)   > 0 $$
It is not the case that $\left(\prod_{i=1}^n x_{\sigma(i)}^{c_i} -1\right)>0$ for all $\sigma \in S_n$.